# C++ TextOut writes random data. Is there a buffer overflow?

Tags: c++, user-interface, winapi

I'm writing some example programs for a programming class using WinAPI. I'm familiar with GUI programming, but not in C++. As part of a test I ran into an anomaly. I'm hoping someone will know what I'm doing wrong and be able to explain the fix. Below is the callback function. Most of the code was copied directly from an example on basic paint.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WinProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM w, LPARAM l)
{
   PAINTSTRUCT ps;
   HDC hdc;
   std::string txt = "Hello\0";
   switch(msg)
   {
      hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
      TextOut(hdc, 0, 60, txt.c_str(), 45);
      EndPain, h, &ps);
   }
}
```

So, the function is supposed to simply print "Hello" on the GUI, but instead I was seeting "Hello  xc". I expanded the length of the string to 45 and saw a lot more. It prints random bits of text. I've seen class names and string values which were going to cout.

I have no idea why this is happening, but it appears that txt is being read far past the end of the buffer. I added a \0. No difference. The value is different every time.

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: simply read documentation - *The string does not need to be zero-terminated, since cbString specifies the length of the string.* you must pass correct string len,but not 45

Comment: So, the fifth parameter must exactly match the length of the string? Is that intentional? Isn't it possible to create exactly this sort of overflow without any boundary checking? I know C++ doesn't always provide such protections, but that seems like a security hazard.

Comment: @BSD - nothing to do with the choice of language. It's the WinApi and your refusal to honour it's expectations

Comment: Let's not be so touchy. I'm not asking an unreasonable question. Suppose that someone makes that length a static value because the answer is always 25 characters. Later a value is printed with only 2 characters. That exposes 23 characters of any data. This is heartbleed all over again. I'm just curious if this is an intentional design decision.

Comment: Replace `45` with `txt.length()`

Comment: @RbMm I'd like to award you the point as you answered first. would you put it into an answer, please.

Comment: `EndPain`. An apt typo. Posting real code is always best.

Comment: *"I have no idea why this is happening"* - That's odd, because the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145133.aspx) is pretty concise. *"I'm not asking an unreasonable question."* - It's completely unreasonable to violate a documented contract and and maintain **any** expectations.

Comment: @BSD - C & C++ give you great power and the ability to shoot yourself in the foot. It's your responsibility to ensure you don't do it.Someone that makes length a fixed value of 25 characters when they may later wish to print just 2 shouldn't have a gun license. With full control comes great responsibility - simple as that. Are cars flawed because inattentive drivers can crash them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TextOut uses the final parameter cchString to determine how many characters to print. You must tell it the correct number.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145133.aspx

> lpString [in]
>   A pointer to the string to be drawn. The string does not need to be zero-terminated, because cchString specifies the length of the string.
>
> cchString [in]
>   The length of the string pointed to by lpString, in characters.

Comment: So, in order to allow strings without a \0 the API requires the exact length of the string? This decision was made to increase the flexibility for lpString?

Comment: @BSD Really? You are asking us to read the mind of the API developers that wrote the API over 25 years ago?  Our psychic powers aren't that great.

Answer (score -1):

`TextOut()` does not stop writing text at the null terminator, it will just keep going for as long as you specified. The last parameter tells the function how many characters to write. Instead of giving it 45, give it something like `strlen(txt.c_str())`.

Comment: Better yet, just use the std::string's own method, `size()`

Comment: Definitely don't use `strlen`!